# Access dictionary value using Spark dataframe column as key

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, utf

I have a dictionary below called sample.

```
sample = {
     10:1
     20:2
     30:3
}
```

I have a dataframe column called age for example and the column contains 10. I want to use this dataframe column as the key lookup to give me the value 1 if the key is 10 for example.

```
    df.withColumn("NewColumnname", dict.get(col("age")))
```

> unhashable type: 'Column'

is coming up but not sure what way to use the column in the dataframe as a key lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to look up the entire column in the dict, and this doesn't work, because a. columns are unhashable and b. there is never going to be a key in the dict which contains *the entire column*.

Clearly what you want to do is to look up *each individual value* in the column in the dict.  Thre are two ways to do this, the right one depending on what you want to do with the data.  Either make your dict into a dataframe and do it in pandas, or iterate the column and lookup.  The latter is probably what you want here and would like something like this:

```
df["NewColumnname"] = df["age"].apply(lambda x: sample[x])
```

**EDIT** on second thoughts that lambda is a bit useless, and this *is* a usecase for .get:

```py
df["new"] = df["age"].apply(sample.get)
```

Note that whilst dicts have a .get method, it's more pythonic to use [] access if you're just looking up a value which you know is there.

### Returning

This modifies df, so we can simply add:

```py
return df
```

and get df out of a function.  If you need to work on a copy, make one first and then add the column in the same way.

### Demonstration

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[7],[8]], columns=["col"])
d = {7: "seven", 8: "eight"}
df["new"] = df["col"].apply(d.get)
print(df)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can use .withColumn(""NewColumnname", col("age").apply(lambda x: sample[x]))

I get  
> 'Column' object is not callable 

but would like to use withColumn if possible.

Comment: Why do you want to use .withColumn?  what are you trying to do with the looked up value when you get it?

Comment: I want to do something like below. I keep getting 'Column' object is not callable trying either way. Do I need a udf?


return df.withColumn("NewColumnname", col("age").apply(lambda x: sample[x])).withColumn("DOB","DOB1").SELECT("NewColumnname","DOB")

Comment: just return df.  Your problem here seems to be doing col("age") rather than col["age"]: note the square brackets

Comment: df["new"] = df["age"].apply(sample.get) returns TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: @lunbox see the demonstration code I added, which runs for me.

Comment: @2e0byo I don't think this is pandas question

Comment: Thanks it worked but what happens if dictionary includes string a30:3 and 30:3 and the df colum contains int and strings. I have huge amount of numbers in dictionary so not feasible to convert all numbers to strings as using range.

Any ideas what best approach for this.

Comment: @lunbox I'm not quite sure what the problem is here.  do you just want to coerce the lookup to be one type or the other?  It would help to *edit the question* with an example of what you mean :)

Answer (score 0):

`withColumn`'s second argument is a `Column` object, that's why you got that error. If all you want is to do that lookup, then the best way is to do an inner join. I'd recommend avoiding UDF as much as possible.

**converting your original dict to a "lookup" dataframe**

```py
sample = {10:1, 20:2, 30:3}

dict_df = spark.createDataFrame([(k, v) for k,v in sample.items()], schema = ['k', 'v'])

# +---+---+
# |  k|  v|
# +---+---+
# | 10|  1|
# | 20|  2|
# | 30|  3|
# +---+---+
```

**this is sample dataframe**

```py
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(10,), (20,), (30,)]).toDF(['col'])

# +---+
# |col|
# +---+
# | 10|
# | 20|
# | 30|
# +---+
```

**perform inner join to get the lookup value**

```py
df.join(dict_df, on=[dict_df.k == df.col])

# +---+---+---+
# |col|  k|  v|
# +---+---+---+
# | 10| 10|  1|
# | 30| 30|  3|
# | 20| 20|  2|
# +---+---+---+
```

Comment: Is there a diffrent way rather than creating a new df?

Comment: 1) you cannot refer a dict like the way you want while performing Spark transformation, I cannot think of any other solution at this moment, and 2) why not?